# Fundamental matrix of a Markov chain

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, markov-process

In [Grinstead & Snell (2006)](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf), on page 417, the authors discuss how to find the 'fundamental matrix' of an absorbing Markov chain. They define two matrices:

1. The matrix $\textbf{I}$ is "an *r*-by-*r* identity matrix", where *r* is the number of absorbing states.
2. The matrix $\textbf{Q}$ as "a *t*-by-*t* matrix", where *t* is the number of transient states. $\textbf{Q}$ is the matrix of transition probabilities between each of the transient states.

Later on (p.419), they calculate the matrix $\textbf{I-Q}$. Apologies if I am showing my naivety, but how can you subtract matrices of different sizes?

On the [relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Fundamental_matrix), the same operation is discussed but $\textbf{I}$ is defined not as the identity matrix for the *absorbing* states but rather as the identity matrix for the *transient* states. Now the two matrices $\textbf{I}$ and $\textbf{Q}$ are the same size and we can subtract one from the other.

Is this a simple typo in Grinstead & Snell (2006), or am I being dim? (i.e. when $\textbf{I}$ is introduced, should it just be defined as a *t*-by-*t* identity matrix, rather than an *r*-by-*r* identity matrix?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf I$ can represent an identity matrix of any size depending on the context, so $\mathbf I$ in the expression of $\mathbf I-\mathbf Q$ should be interpreted as the $t\times t$ identity matrix to match the size of $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: Aha, I see! That makes a lot of sense - thanks.